# How to send cookie with AVPlayer url in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes, session-cookies, avplayer

Is it possible to send cookie with the AVPlayer url?I have a livestream which is AES encrypted and needs a key to decrypt.It will hit the server and the server returns the key only if session is there.So I want to send phpsessionid along with the url to AVPlayer.

Is it possible? I saw `AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey`.I don't know if it is what I have to set.If so how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
   This is how you can set Signed Cookies (Headers) in AVPlayer URL Request :

    fileprivate func setPlayRemoteUrl() {
        if playUrl.isEmpty { return }
        let cookiesArray = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!
        let values = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookiesArray)
        let cookieArrayOptions = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": values]
        let assets = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL! as URL, options: cookieArrayOptions)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer?.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
    }
```

Comment: It was an old post. But thanks for the answer. it might work I guess.

Answer (score 3):

In your case FPS(FairPlay Streaming) by apple will work. FairPlay Streaming is DRM(Digital Right Management) support where you will get content key along with your content data and you need to pass through delegate which supports AES-128 encrypt. Please refer below link which i shared below

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really tried it myself but it seems there's an API that let's you create `AVURLAsset` with `options`.  One of the possible option key is `AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey`.  You might want to look into that.

Comment: By default AVPlayer is sending the cookie along with the request .Seems like the player sends the cookie if available.Anyway thanks for the answer.